# Router is appending the path at the end

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-router, react-router-dom

I have many `component` in react page. in my `router` file I have used them like below.

```
  <SecureRoute path="/new-inventory">
            <Inventory />
        </SecureRoute>

        <SecureRoute path="/list-inventory">
            <ListInventory />
        </SecureRoute>


        <SecureRoute exact path="/:id/edit" component={EditInventory} />
```

below path gets called within the component

```
   <SecureRoute exact path="/:id/edit" component={EditInventory} />
```

I am using below `anchor` tag.

`<a href={/${props.inventory.id}/edit`}>

path in browser gets generated like this

```
http://localhost:4200/36917491-4ef5-4fa2-87aa-c921986f94d1/edit
```

now if I click on otther tab for ex `inventory` then instead of coming `url` like
http://localhost:4200/inventory   it comes like  `http://localhost:4200/36917491-4ef5-4fa2-87aa-c921986f94d1/edit/inventory`

means path gets appended instead of replacing. what should I do?

Comment: Try placing your edit route above your other routes.

Comment: what version of `react-router` you are using

Comment: "react-router-dom": "^5.2.0",

Comment: @StephanBakkelundValois still smae issue

Comment: Don't use raw anchor `<a />` tags when navigating internally within your app. Can you update your question to include a more complete and comprehensive code example? https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: I actually tried but code is so integrated and complex so it is not even compiling.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using `anchor` tags use `Link` that comes with react-router. `anchor` tags will trigger page reload while `Link` do not.

```
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";

<Link to="/list-inventory">Inventory</Link>list-inventory
```

Comment: that did not solve the problem actually.

Comment: What is happening? Can you post what you did?

Comment: same , I mean code is working but with same issue.

Comment: Can you create a sandbox and show us what you are doing?